# Double borders with different widths

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to implement a double border as shown below with CSS - *ideally without using extra elements*.

[image: double border]

My initial thought would be to apply the first border to the container element, and the second to the title element below.

```css
.box {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
h2 {
  float: left;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

The main issue here is that the requirement may be that the width of the small border is indepedent of the width of the text. Also we may run into problems with line-height / vertical text alignment.

Are there are other viable solutions to this problem?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the second border stretch to the full width of the parent here? This is how I interpreted your question in my answer below.

Comment: I'm asking how to implement the borders as shown in the image. (color not taken into account)

Comment: With at least minimal knowledge about CSS you should have been able to adjust the `::before` solution to your actual needs by yourself. Nonetheless, since you now clarified your requirements, I added the adjusted `::before`-based solution to my answer.

Comment: Also, your question title is kind of misleading since you are talking about borders with different width. Anyone would assume you're talking `border-width` here. Your code example even supports that assumption since you are actually using different `border-width` on both elements.

Comment: Yeah actually I just used the solution I gave in my own question so in that sense the question is obsolete. I'd delete it but I can't

Answer (score -1):

I hope the below CSS code will help you.

```css
.box{
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
}

h2{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
}
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers.